# Understand ByteCode which print something

Tags: java, bytecode

Please help what this bytecode will print

```
BIPUSH 10
BIPUSH 7
IXOR
ISTORE 1
IINC 1 19
GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ILOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend reading the JVM specification, which explains everything.

Going through your specific example

```
BIPUSH 10
```

This pushes 10 onto the stack

```
BIPUSH 7
```

This pushes 7 onto the stack. The stack is now 10 7

```
IXOR
```

This xors the top two elements. The stack is now 10^7 = 13

```
ISTORE 1
```

This stores the top element in local variable slot 1. The stack is now empty, while the locals are [INVALID, 13]

```
IINC 1 19
```

This increments local 1 by 19. The locals are now [INVALID, 32]

```
GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

This pushes System.out onto the stack

```
ILOAD 1
```

This loads the variable onto the stack

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
```

And this prints it. So the final result is printing `32`.

This bytecode was probably generated by Java code along the lines of the following

```
int x = 10 ^ 7;
x += 19;
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Thanks! You help much! May be u can advice some resources to learn about JVM from  start level?

Comment: The JVM specification is the best resource. That's where I started.

Comment: It’s hard, if not impossible, to find equivalent Java code producing this bytecode, due to the way, Java treats constant values. Any attempt of preventing the Java compiler from treating `10 ^ 7` as compile time constant, will lead to the generation of additional bytecode instructions. Regarding JVM spec, [that’s the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/index.html)…

Comment: Thanks everybody for answers!

Comment: @Holger I couldn't remember if the constant expression optimization applied to bitwise operations like that or not. But at any rate, it's still the closest equivalent understandable to someone who doesn't know bytecode.

Comment: That’s actually easy to remember, as *all* basic arithmetic operators form constant expressions when all operands are constant expressions. So you only have to remember the exceptions, first, operators with side effects (`++` and `--`), second, expressions whose evaluation will fail with an exception (e.g., `1/0`). But yes, your example is the closest Java equivalent, it just might be useful to note that the bytecode of the question is actually unlikely to originate from Java source code (as we don’t know the question’s context).